# mod_rewrite RewriteRule for pretty URL in Concrete5

Tags: mod-rewrite, concrete5-8.x

Concrete5 provides this config dump to insert an elided 'index.php/' at the beginning of all URLs:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But why does the `RewriteRule` work?

1. Why does the replacement string go at the beginning of the URL, and
   where does the extra '/' come from? E.g `http://<host>/foo` ==>
   `http://<host>/index.php/foo`.
2. Why doesn't this rule require [QSA] to preserve query string parameters?

The rule objectively does handle both these cases correctly, but I cannot deduce from the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) why it does, and would appreciate some patient instructor reading the relevant sections of the farking manual to me.